# Limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty} e^{-e^{xy}}$ with polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, limits-without-lhopital

can i use polar to solve this limit?
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty} e^{-e^{xy}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{e^{e^{r^2\cos\theta\sin \theta}}}=$$
but i'm quite stuck here i think the denominator goes to infinity but should i show that? or can i just write $0$ as a solution after the step above like
$$\frac{1}{e^{e^{r^2\cos\theta\sin \theta}}}=0$$
is it correct?
any help or suggestion would be very helpful
Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use polar coordinates but the final evaluation is not correct indeed by $x=y=t \to \infty$ we obtain

$$e^{-e^{xy}}=e^{-e^{t^2}} \to 0$$

but for $x=-y=t \to \infty$ we obtain

$$e^{-e^{xy}}=e^{-e^{-t^2}} \to e^0=1$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.